# home directory not mounted as proper partition

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, mount

I'm running into some trouble getting my `/home` directory to mount with the correct drive partition.

Currently, if I view my `/home/bot/ftp/www` folder, I cannot see a few files ex: "stats.php" and "processing.php".
However, if I run `mount /dev/sda3 /mnt` and check the `/mnt` folder, I can see these files present in `/mnt/bot/ftp/www`.

When I attempt to mount `/dev/sda3` to the home directory, it gives me this error:

```
root@xxxxxx:/# mount /dev/sda3 /home
mount: /home: /dev/sda3 already mounted on /home.
```

This confused me quite a bit, because the contents of `/home/bot/ftp/www` are different than the contents of `/dev/sda3` when it was mounted to the `/mnt/` folder.

Is there a possibility that I have accidentally linked something else to this directory?

Any help is much appreciated, Thank you :)

Comment: it is possible that you mounted something else to /home/bot/ftp/www which would hide the original contents of the folder.

Comment: @ravery What's the best method to viewing mounts?

Comment: `mount` without arguments will list all active mount points